# Need help understanding this text regarding Taylor series expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

[image: IMAGE1]
[image: IMAGE2]

I am able to understand this text except for the side note where they have mentioned:

> To be precise equation $12.8$ holds for $n\ge1$ and equation $12.9$
>   holds for $n\ge2$. But since equation 12.8 is $0$ for $n=1$ and
>   equation 12.9 is $0$ for $n=1,2$, both equations hold for all $n\ge0$.

I can understand that equation $12.8$ holds for $n\ge1$ as we have derived it to calculate the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ and if if we put $n=0$, we'll be calculating the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ which is wrong. Can anyone one confirm if this explanation is correct?

And I can't understand the second part of this side note at all, i.e., But since equation 12.8 is $0$ for $n=1$ and equation 12.9 is $0$ for $n=1,2$, both equations hold for all $n\ge0$.

Comment: The formulas in 12.8 and 12.9 is only valid for certain $n$, they were obtained under assumptions. However, the formulas obtained can be applied to any $n$ if you take them out of context: $n(n+1)(n+2) = 0 for n = 0$, and thus can be extended in context to all $n$ values. It's akin to a concept called **extension** in analytics for limit of functions.

Comment: @jean How is equation 12.8 $0$ for $n=1$?

Comment: 12.8 is valid for $n \geq 1$ so only need to extend it for $0$ while 12.9 is valid for $n \geq 2$ so need to extend it for $1$ and $0$